# Zend studio for eclipse - where does it store it's project files on a mac?

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio

I'm refering to the .xml congig files with stuff like the path to the project's files in it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you look into your "~/Library/Application Support/" ?